# When creating a JS XPCOM Service can classID be random?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

When I create a JS XPCOM service the guid that is used for the classID can just be a randomly generated string correct? [following directions here?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Generating_GUIDs)

I ask because I'm forking another project and changed this to a another randomly generated value, and I believe I changed the classDescription, and contractID correctly as well, but I'm not having any success. So I just wanted to check that my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a new addon and a new service to test out my assumption, and you can use a random [guid created from a site like this](http://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen).